# How to work with multi hamburger menu in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have successfully added two hamburger menus in a single web-page using bootstrap. 
Now, I have a problem, When I collapse the right one, then I collapse the left one, **both of them stay collapsed**.
What I want is, to have one of them collapsed at the same time.

I found the similar problem [on this code][1].

Thank you for any support

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/kXAYGz
```

Comment: Without JS/jQuery?

Comment: if it can be solved without js or jquery, it will be great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fork your codepen and added some js to your code.  
  `codepen.io/ayang10/pen/gROMvZ`

add this to your js file

```
 $(function(){
    $('.navbar .navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
        $('.navbar .navbar-collapse').not(this).collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Monkey_dev1300, this is what I am looking for... Is it possible to do the same without using JS?

Comment: you can probably work some magic with css but it might get a bit complicated.